# How to get value from a Java enum

Tags: java, enums

I have a enum which looks like:

```
public enum Constants{
  YES("y"), NO("N")
  private String value;

  Constants(String value){
    this.value = value;
  }
}
```

I have a test class which looks like

```
public class TestConstants{
 public static void main(String[] args){
   System.out.println(Constants.YES.toString())
   System.out.println(Constants.NO.toString())
 }
}
```

The output is:

```
YES
NO
```

instead of

```
Y
N
```

I am not sure what is wrong here ??

Comment: why do you expect that `toString()` returns the value?

Answer (score 35, accepted):

You need to **override** the `toString` method of your enum:

```
public enum Constants{
    YES("y"), NO("N")

    // No changes

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return value;
    }
}
```

Comment: Maybe, maybe not. Maybe the OP needs a separate `getValue()` method instead?

Comment: Maybe, but the OP is explicitly calling the un-overriden `toString()` method of his enum, which pretty much sums it all.

Comment: What is a better practice. Overriding the toString() method or writing a separate getter method ??

Comment: getter method is simplier, but both of solutions are ok.

Comment: Although this solution works, it only works for this SPECIFIC problem. If a "googler" comes here and the enum he or she needs to obtain the value from has non-String values, this solution will not work. As as common practice, you should not use the `toString()` to return values. That violates the `Object.toString()` API. In addition, overriding this method works only for `String` values. Instead, you should create a `getValue()` function that returns the appropriate data type. See David Yee's or Just a Logic Gate's answer. They are more correct than this one, regardless of the OPs vote.

Comment: @Mandar See my previous comment. It is better to create a getter method than to use `toString` for more than one reason.

Comment: @hfontanez The OP is asking why do the `toString` calls not return the result he expected. Your solution changes the code that the OP is trying to get to work.

Comment: @MohammedAoufZouag incorrect. That is what you assumed he asked and your assumption is wrong. The title is clear "How to get a value from a Java enum". Then concludes his post with "I am not sure what is wrong here ??" One of the things he is doing wrong is making use of the `Object#toString()` method because it violates the intent of the function. Instead of allowing the OP to create a working incorrect solution, we should advice him/her to create a better solution. Sorry to say, but this answer is not the best. Aside from that, other people who come here for answers will be misinformed.

Comment: @hfontanez incorrect. The OP is complaining why the current output of his program doesn't match what he expected, and provided the code he used for that purpose. He gave a specific question (regardless of the generic title), for a specific situation, which requires a specific answer. If you feel like farming some reputation, feel free to post your own answer with all the details you want.

Comment: @MohammedAoufZouag this is not about "farming reputation". This is about not reading between the lines. The question is clear and very open-ended "I am not sure what is wrong here ??"  He is doing many things wrong and regardless how good you feel about your answer, it is not the best answer; which is why thee other people answered differently than you and their answer is almost the same when compared to one another. Yes, your answer is technically correct, as I stated on my original post. But in the greater scheme of things, it wasn't the best advice.

Answer (score 16):

You can also add a getter to the enumeration and simply call on it to access the instance variable:

```
public enum Constants{
    YES("Y"), NO("N");
    private String value;

    public String getResponse() {
        return value;
    }

    Constants(String value){
        this.value = value;
    }
}

public class TestConstants{
    public static void main(String[] args){
        System.out.println(Constants.YES.getResponse());
        System.out.println(Constants.NO.getResponse());
    }
}
```

Comment: Regardless of the OP's vote, this is the correct solution. See my comment in the "Best Answer" post.

Answer (score 12):

Create a getValue() method in your enum, and use this instead of toString().

```
public enum Constants{
 YES("y"), NO("N")
 private String value;

 Constants(String value){
  this.value = value;
 }
}

 public String getValue(){
  return value;
 }
```

And instead of:

```
System.out.println(Constants.YES.toString())
System.out.println(Constants.NO.toString())
```

(Which are also missing a semi-colon), use

```
System.out.println(Constants.YES.getValue());
System.out.println(Constants.NO.getValue());
```

Hope this solved your problem. If you do not want to create a method in your enum, you can make your value field public, but this would break encapsulation.

Comment: Regardless of the OP's vote, this is the correct solution. See my comment in the "Best Answer" post.

Answer (score 7):

Write Getter and Setter for `value` and use:

```
System.out.println(Constants.YES.getValue());
System.out.println(Constants.NO.getValue());
```

Answer (score 0):

```
String enumValue = Constants.valueOf("YES")
```

Java doc ref: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Enum.html#valueOf(java.lang.Class,%20java.lang.String)

Comment: Why use `valueOf`? This is more error prone than to use the enum itself and call its getter method.

Answer (score 0):

The elegant way to get value of an Enum is by using **ordinal** method.

```
public enum Constants
{
  YES("Y"), NO("N");
  private String value;

public String getResponse() {
    return value;
}

Constants(String value){
    this.value = value;
}
public static Constants getConstants(int value){
    for(Constants e : Constants.values()){
        if(value == e.getResponse()) return e;
    }
    return null;
  }
}

public class TestConstants{
public static void main(String[] args)
  {
    System.out.println(Constants.YES.ordinal());
    System.out.println(Constants.NO.ordinal());
  }
}
```